# Manually altering postgres schema leads to the error: current transaction aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block (django app)

Tags: django, database, postgresql, transactions, postgresql-9.3

I have a Django model called `Message`:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sending_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I added `sender = models.ForeignKey(User)` to this model in my Django code. Next, I wanted to explore doing changes in the postgresql table **manually**, without invoking `syncdb` or `south`.

So I logged into `psql` and did the following:

```
ALTER TABLE message ADD COLUMN "sender" INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
ALTER TABLE message ADD CONSTRAINT fk_message_user FOREIGN KEY (sender) REFERENCES user(id);
```

With those two commands, I successfully added a new column with default value 1, containing a foreign key to Django's built-in `User` model.

After I had done that, I figured I had successfully approximated what Django does with `syncdb` or `south`. I ran my web app - everything looked good. But then as soon as I hit the first database transaction in my code, the following error resulted:

> DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until
>   end of transaction block

I'm unable to get it to work unless I delete the column I manually added (or rollback the transaction), but not otherwise. `syncdb` is an option, but let's exclude it for this question.

What did I miss when I manually provisioned that foreignkey field? Can someone walk me through the process? I'm assuming running a migration simply automates steps one could have done *manually* too. I need to understand the anatomy of that process, hence doing it by hand. That's what this question's about.

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: After you manually create a field in your DB you also have to add the field to your `Models.py` too. Don't forget to create the foreign key in your DB if necessary and maybe even a DB index. You can always run `--fake` when you want to add field manually and run migrations. BTW is the 50 char limit enough of text field in your message Model? Edit: Also note that you have to run the migration at least once so Django can create all the dependable tables in your DB!

Comment: Guys like I mentioned, I added `sender = models.ForeignKey(User)` to my model before tinkering around in psql. If I were to do it manually without running any migrations, what would be the steps? I'm assuming *running a migration* simply automates steps one could have done manually too. I need to understand the anatomy of that process, hence doing it by hand. That's what this question's about.